# How to open a file in python which has it's name appended with date?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a file with open method in python where in my given filename will be appended with date using datetime method as follows

```
import datetime
f=open('myfile.txt_'+str(datetime.datetime.now()),'w')
print(f.name)
```

I get an error

```
File "C:/Users/nitjoshi2/PycharmProjects/Lab/list.py", line 2, in <module>
f=open('myfile.txt_'+str(datetime.datetime.now()),'w')
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'myfile.txt_2019-01-24 
01:12:42.395125'
```

Kindly explain the error as i can see the desired output i.e myfile.txt_2019-01-24 
01:12:42.395125 in error message but not getting the file as output

Comment: Colons aren't allowed in Windows filenames.

Comment: Ahh, forgot about this. I'm a linux developer

Comment: yup skipped my mind too!! thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is the file is supposed to be a `*.txt` file so you're creating the filename as `myfile.txt_2019-01-24` and not `myfile_2019-01-24.txt` this is an easy fix.

*Also, it's recomended you use `with open() as f` instead of `f=open()` as it will automatically close the file for you no need to `f.close()`.*

**Edit**

Although as pointed out by @jasonharper you cannot have a filename with colons so you will need to format it without time.

```
import datetime
with open('myfile{}_.txt'.format(strftime('%Y-%m%d %H-%M', datetime.datetime.now())),'w') as f:
    print(f.name)
    #myfile_2019-01-24 01-12-42 .txt
```

Comment: You probably want to put the underscore after the myfile not the txt and use .date() to get only the date without the time.
`with open('myfile_{}.txt'.format(datetime.datetime.now().date()), 'w') as f:` - will probably need to use `strfromtime` to get time without colons